# Raspberry Pi: Embedded Programming Exercise, Getting Started

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi

First, I am following this tutorial here (http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/os/).

In the first exercise you learn about addressing the GPIO pin that is responsible for turning on the green okay LED. I have the rev C of the Raspberry pi which to my knowledge uses the Broadcom (BCM2835) micro processor which has the following datasheet for its peripherals: (http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/os/downloads/SoC-Peripherals.pdf).

I have read pages 89 through 104 of the data sheet but I am still lost. The program provided by the author does not seem to run even with the cross compiler build chain provided. Striping the comments out of the source provided by the author I have:

```
.section .init
.global _start
_start:
  ldr r0, =0x20200000

  /* Enable output on the 16th pin */
  mov r1, #1
  lsl r1, #18
  str r1, [r0, #4]

  /* Turn the pin off to turn LED light on */
  mov r1,#1
  lsl r1,#16
  str r1, [r0, #40]

loop$:
  /* Keep the system running */
  b loop$
```

Where I am stuck is, in the data sheet I see nothing about the address 0x20200000. Starting On page 91 in the table 6-2 we see the tables which describe the first 32 bits. And in table 6-1 we see a register description. The address of the first register is 0x7E200000. I have tried to use this address in its place but I still had no luck getting the light to turn on.

Bottom line the LED light does not turn on, and so I can learn, where should I go to get information on how to debug this? Secondly, what am I missing?

If it is useful, here is a hexdump of the img file that I am dd'ing to the SD card.

```
mehoggan@mehoggan-desktop:~/Devel/scripts/assembly/raspberry-pi-mini-os/example1$ make clean all
rm -f build/*.o 
rm -f build/output.elf
rm -f kernel.img
rm -f kernel.list
rm -f kernel.map
../arm-2008q3/bin/arm-none-eabi-as -I source/ source/main.s -o build/main.o
../arm-2008q3/bin/arm-none-eabi-ld --no-undefined build/main.o -Map kernel.map -o build/output.elf -T kernel.ld
../arm-2008q3/bin/arm-none-eabi-objcopy build/output.elf -O binary kernel.img 
../arm-2008q3/bin/arm-none-eabi-objdump -d build/output.elf > kernel.list
mehoggan@mehoggan-desktop:~/Devel/scripts/assembly/raspberry-pi-mini-os/example1$ 

hexdump -C ./kernel.img 
00000000  18 00 9f e5 01 10 a0 e3  01 19 a0 e1 04 10 80 e5  |................|
00000010  01 10 a0 e3 01 18 a0 e1  28 10 80 e5 fe ff ff ea  |........(.......|
00000020  00 00 20 20                                       |..  |
```

---

***EDIT***
Here is the .list file

```
00000000 <_start>:
   0:   e59f0018    ldr r0, [pc, #24]   ; 20 <loop$+0x4>
   4:   e3a01001    mov r1, #1  ; 0x1
   8:   e1a01901    lsl r1, r1, #18
   c:   e5801004    str r1, [r0, #4]
  10:   e3a01001    mov r1, #1  ; 0x1
  14:   e1a01801    lsl r1, r1, #16
  18:   e5801028    str r1, [r0, #40]

0000001c <loop$>:
  1c:   eafffffe    b   1c <loop$>
  20:   20200000    .word   0x20200000
```

If you reverse the endianess of the hexdump you see it lines up with the .list file.

```
e59f0018
e3a01001
e1a01901
e5801004
e3a01001
e1a01801
e5801028
eafffffe
20200000
```

Comment: @dwelch one sec rebooting and I will get that to you.

Comment: Im still confused where the constant went, try changing the ldr r0,=0x2020000 to two lines mov r0,#0x20000000 ; orr r0,r0,#0x00200000

Comment: the broadcom docs do describe the gpio, you will see that the memory space that contains the peripherals starts at 0x7E000000 that is mapped into ARM memory space at 0x20000000.  So a peripheral at 0x7E20000 is address in arm memory space at 0x20200000.

Comment: the schematic shows which gpio pin is connected to the led

Comment: the raspberrypi.org forums have described these examples in great detail.

Comment: Thanks I will look there. As for the your third comment. What page are you looking at?

Comment: @dwelch I blotched the hexdump. Please see the revised dump

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29424/discussion-between-matthew-hoggan-and-dwelch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the schematic (as well as the page you linked where you found this code) gpio 16 is connected to that status led

> Where I am stuck is, in the data sheet I see nothing about the address
>   0x20200000

that is not true, page 6 of the bcm manual:

Physical addresses range from 0x20000000 to 0x20FFFFFF for peripherals. The bus addresses for peripherals are set up to map onto the peripheral bus address range starting at 0x7E000000. Thus a peripheral advertised here at bus address 0x7Ennnnnn is available at 
physical address 0x20nnnnnn.

With that take the info from the example program 0x20200000 becomes 0x7E200000 which is the gpio registers,

specifically 0x7E200004 is GPFSEL1

The description for GPFSEL1 says that the bit pattern 001 makes the pin an output, and it shows that the bits in that register for gpio 16 are bits 18-20 so we want to put the bit pattern 001 at bit 18 so 1<<18 is written to 0x7E200004

40 decimal is 28 hex so the second register of interest is 0x7E200028 which is is GPCLR0

The GPCLRn description says that if a bit is set then the gpio output is cleared. So write a 1<<16 to that register to pull the output to zero, which turns on the led

Then go into an infinite loop so nothing else happens (to/from the ARM).

Your hex file (with the update/edit) is fine.  The only files you want on the sd card or at least in the root diretory of the first partition are  bootcode.bin and start.elf from the firmware directory of http://github.com/raspberrypi dont need/get any other files from there.  Your binary file kernel.img also goes on the sd card.  Nothing else.  plug in the sd card, plug in the raspberry pi.  If it doesnt work right off then unplug and replug (there is a cache thing that can happen) and it should work the second time.  If that doesnt work, repartition and re-format the sd card and try again, I have had something happen a number of times that prevents the sd card from working in a raspberry pi.

EDIT:

Down the road you may run into troubles as the linker script is apparently building your binary to be based at address 0x0000 rather than 0x8000.  You can put a config.txt file in the root directory on the sd card and inside a line that enables legacy kernel mode or something that tells the GPU to load kernel.img to address 0x0000 rather than 0x8000, or modify the linker script such that .text (and everything else) starts at 0x8000.  The specific OK01 example program happens to be position independent so it can be run from any address, so the minimal three files (bootcode.bin, start.elf, kernel.img) will work.